# pgfmathparse inside tikz child doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, pgfmath

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {} child foreach \i in {1,2,3} {node {$\i$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I add a `\pgfmathparse{}` inside the child braces, like this

```
\node {} child foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\pgfmathparse{1+1} node {$\i$}};
```

the following Error occurs:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

### Edit

Essentially I want to make conditional drawing of childs as in

```
\node (O) {} child foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \ifthenelse{\i=2}{}{node {$\i$}}
};
```

But I need some `\pgfmathparse` commands to evaluate more complicated conditions first.

Comment: move the math parsing into the node content.

Comment: I want to make the drawing of a child dependent on some circumstances. Essentially I thought of something like `\pgfmathparse{\i=2?0:1}` (and if `1` draw the child, and if `0` don't draw the child).
Therefore it the evalulation needs to be there, where it is, I guess.

Comment: Can you adjust your MWE to reflect what exactly what you want? This is simply writing math stuff in a node but what you describe is different.

Comment: @percusse I added an Edit section to my qustion.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\node (O) {} child foreach[evaluate={\j=(\i==2?:"node{$\i$}")}] \i in {1,2,3} {\j};` or `\node (O) {} child foreach[evaluate={\j=(\i==2?"edge from parent[draw=none]":"node{$\i$}")}] \i in {1,2,3} {\j};`

Comment: @esdd This looks promising, but I dont want to make a specific child invisible. I just want to draw the tree as if the specific child doesn't exist (so there is no blank space from that child).

Comment: I think this is not possible using `foreach` inside the child. Even if your code with `\ifthenelse` would work the result would be `\node (O) {} child{node{1}} child  child{node{3}};`.

Answer (score 8):

TikZ has its own parser for creating paths and a slightly different parser for children in trees. So it isn't possible to stick arbitrary code just anywhere.

Inside normal paths code can be wrapped inside the `\pgfextra` command, but this isn't allowed in trees. If it is simply evaluation required then the (possibly still undocumented) `evaluate` key can be used in the foreach loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {} child foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(\i*3);}] in {1,2,3} { node {$\i:\j$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or as @percusse  points out in his comment above, do the math inside the node.

Comment: Thanks so far for this useful information.
I think I should have gone further with my needs.
As I pointed out above in a comment to my question, I want to do a conditional drawing of the childs. And I think therefore the code should be in that position I choose in my question, I guess.